# What is the difference between events and helpers?

Tags: meteor

What is the difference between `Meteor.templateName.events` and `Meteor.templateName.helpers`.

and how do I know which one I need to implement for my template?

Comment: have you read the documentation yet? Which part were you unclear about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, helpers are functions you can use with {{}} as if they were variables in your Blaze templates. Events are functions you can bind to DOM events. 
Example:

Template:

```html
<template name="example">
    <button>{{buttonLabel}}</button>
</template>
```

JS:

```js
Template.example.helpers({
     'buttonLabel': function(){ return "Click me"; }
});
Template.example.events({
    'click button': function() {
        // put your action here
        console.log("button was clicked");
    }
});
```

With this, your template will have a button with the label "Click me", returned by the buttonLabel helper. And when you click the button, the code inside the function bound to a button click event will be triggered (in this case, just printing "button was clicked" on the console).